# Pivot and Unpivot for 4 joined table SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

I'm using SQL Server 2012, and I want to create a pivot table with 4 joined tables.

Here's my query :

```
SELECT 
    a.Itemno, a.Qty as PlanMilling, 
    ISNULL(b.MinimStock, 0) as MinStock, 
    CAST(a.ScheduleDate as Date) AS Schedule, 
    ISNULL(SUM(c.Qty), 0) as QtyBuilding,
    ISNULL(d.RunQty, 0) as QtyStock, 
    d.itemcode, 
    ISNULL((a.Qty + d.RunQty) - SUM(c.Qty), 0) as Balance
FROM 
    Schedule a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Item b ON a.ItemNo = b.ItemNo
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    ShopOrderList c on a.ItemNo = c.ItemNo and a.ScheduleDate = c.ScheduleDate
LEFT OUTER JOIN  
    (SELECT  
         RunQty, ItemCode  
     FROM
         ICMutTran a
     INNER JOIN
         (SELECT 
              itemcode as ItemNo, max(id) as maxid 
          FROM
              ICMutTran 
          GROUP BY 
              itemcode) AS b ON a.id = b.maxid) d ON (a.ItemNo = d.ItemCode)
GROUP BY 
    a.ItemNo, a.Qty, b.MinimStock, a.ScheduleDate, d.RunQty, d.itemcode
```

and the result :

```
ItemNo   |   PlanMilling   |   MinStock   |   Schedule   |   QtyBuilding   |   QtyStock   |   ItemCode   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123      |   1000          | 100          | 2016-02-04   | 200             | 1500         | 123          |
123      |   2000          | 100          | 2016-02-05   | 100             | 1500         | 123          |
123      |   1500          | 100          | 2016-02-06   | 150             | 1500         | 123          |
```

What I need is this:

```
ColName     |   2016-02-04   |   2016-02-05   |   2016-02-06   |
----------------------------------------------------------------
PlanMilling |   1000         |   2000         |   1500         |
MinStock    |    100         |    100         |    100         |
QtyBuilding |    200         |    100         |    150         |
QtyStock    |   1500         |   1500         |   1500         |
```

Can anyone solve my case? I really need your help (sorry for my bad english)..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does your PIVOT dynamically on ScheduleDate. You can use this script by rewriting your SELECT statement as

```
SELECT <your selects> INTO #tt FROM <the rest of your query>
```

and use the part of the script after the `CREATE TABLE #tt` and `INSERT INTO #tt` statements. After pivotting don't forget to DROP the temporary table.

```
CREATE TABLE #tt(ItemNo INT,PlanMilling INT,MinStock INT,Schedule VARCHAR(10),QtyBuilding INT,QtyStock INT,ItemCode INT);
INSERT INTO #tt(ItemNo,PlanMilling,MinStock,Schedule,QtyBuilding,QtyStock,ItemCode)VALUES
    (123,1000,100,'2016-02-04',200,1500,123),
    (123,2000,100,'2016-02-05',100,1500,123),
    (123,1500,100,'2016-02-06',150,1500,123);

DECLARE @schedule_dates NVARCHAR(MAX)=STUFF((
    SELECT DISTINCT
        ','+QUOTENAME(Schedule)
    FROM
        #tt
    FOR
        XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,''
);

DECLARE @stmt NVARCHAR(MAX)=N'
    SELECT
        ColName,' +
        @schedule_dates+'
    FROM
        #tt
        UNPIVOT (
            value 
            FOR ColName in (PlanMilling,MinStock,QtyBuilding,QtyStock)
        ) AS up
        PIVOT (
            MAX(value) 
            FOR Schedule IN ('+@schedule_dates+')
        ) AS p;
';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @stmt;

DROP TABLE #tt;
```

Results:

```
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+
|   ColName   | 2016-02-04 | 2016-02-05 | 2016-02-06 |
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+
| MinStock    |        100 |        100 |        100 |
| PlanMilling |       1000 |       2000 |       1500 |
| QtyBuilding |        200 |        100 |        150 |
| QtyStock    |       1500 |       1500 |       1500 |
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: that's really help, thanks ! but, i have a little problem when i put to the store procedure there is no result when i Execute the store procedure

Comment: @Jackques Hi Jackques. I am sorry to hear that. What you do now is first acknowledge that I solved the problem you described in your question, by accepting this answer. Your question made no mention of stored procedures, so it is impossible to now change my answer for a question you ask in a comment. That is not how things are done on StackOverflow. What is best now if you keep experiencing this problem, is to make a new question on StackOverflow, detailing the new problem you have (ie you are not getting output when running this from a Stored Procedure).

Comment: @Jackques When you ask this new question, come back to this answer and give me a comment so that I can find your new question. If nobody answers your new question I will have a look at it.

Comment: @Jackques Just for sports, I wrapped this solution in a Stored Procedure and executed it. This returned the same result as simply running this script. So it is best you ask a new question detailing what you tried as best you can. If you accept this answer I'll make an effort to make sure your problem from running this in a Stored Procedure gets solved. GL!

Comment: sorry TT., that just my little mistake for stored procedure, your query is AWESOME to solve my problem, it really helpful

THANKS A LOT !!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option using `union all` with `conditional aggregation` (although it's a little ugly):

```
with cte as (
    <<your query here>>
)
select 'PlanMilling' ColName,
       max(case when Schedule = '2016-02-04' then PlanMilling end) '2016-02-04',
       max(case when Schedule = '2016-02-05' then PlanMilling end) '2016-02-05',
       max(case when Schedule = '2016-02-06' then PlanMilling end) '2016-02-06'
from cte
union all
select 'MinStock' ColName,
       max(case when Schedule = '2016-02-04' then MinStock end) '2016-02-04',
       max(case when Schedule = '2016-02-05' then MinStock end) '2016-02-05',
       max(case when Schedule = '2016-02-06' then MinStock end) '2016-02-06'
from cte
union all
select 'QtyBuilding' ColName,
       max(case when Schedule = '2016-02-04' then QtyBuilding end) '2016-02-04',
       max(case when Schedule = '2016-02-05' then QtyBuilding end) '2016-02-05',
       max(case when Schedule = '2016-02-06' then QtyBuilding end) '2016-02-06'
from cte
union all
select 'QtyStock' ColName,
       max(case when Schedule = '2016-02-04' then QtyStock end) '2016-02-04',
       max(case when Schedule = '2016-02-05' then QtyStock end) '2016-02-05',
       max(case when Schedule = '2016-02-06' then QtyStock end) '2016-02-06'
from cte
```

Comment: i want to create a pivot  with a dynamic schedule

Comment: @Jackques -- If that's the case, you'll need to look into using `dynamic sql` with pivoting.  Several examples on SO.

Comment: can you share those links to me ? please, i really want to solve this, even it just a syntax